# Auto Increment not working in android SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

I've got a running database but the primary key won't auto increment. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

The code is as following

```
    // Database name and Version
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kmky_database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Table
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "logs";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
private static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
private static final String COLUMN_DATE = "timestamp";
private static final String COLUMN_INCOMING = "incoming";
private static final String COLUMN_OUTGOING = "outgoing";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DATE + " INTEGER, " + COLUMN_INCOMING + " INTEGER, " + COLUMN_OUTGOING + " INTEGER);";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the Primary key as this

```
  ...."(" + COLUMN_ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT.....
```

You forgot the `AUTOINCREMENT` key word thats all.

Comment: No problem, just an oversight, I hope you will remember it from now on as well.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was all I needed after several attempts putting up AUTO_INCREMENT and not working!